android studio settings are not saved/displaying
I am using Android studio on macbook and trying to mirror and view my real phone. I can't find 'device mirroring' option on the menu bar. I tried to change/save the settings, but still not able to see it.
I went to Android Studio/Settings/Tools/Device Mirroring to save the settingsDo I miss anything? it seems straight forward to me, but did not work.
I appreciate any help. Thank you.
